# task continuation messes up the references

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

So some of my code is called asynchronously like this

```
Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync());
```

DoSomethingAsync itself callss DoSomething2Async which looks like this

```
private void DoSomething2Async()
{
    Something something = new Something(3);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        something.a = rand.Next(1000);

        var task = new Task<int>(()
            => Calculate());

        something.ContinueWith((t)
            => CalculateContinuation(something, task.Result));

        task.Start();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Do Something2 is done");
}
```

this is the Calculate() method

```
private int Calculate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        var a = 5; // imitate some job
    }

    return new Random().Next();
}
```

and this is the CalculateContinuation() method

```
private void CalculateContinuation(Something something, int b)
{
    MessageBox.Show(something.a.ToString(), b.ToString());
}
```

and this is the class Something

```
class Something : ICloneable
{
    public int a;

    public Something(int aa)
    {
        a = aa;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Something clone = new Something(a);

        return clone;
    }
}
```

as you see `Calculate` is called 3 times and `CalculateContinuation` will also be called 3 times and I want to pass to the CalculateContinuation 2 parameters one would be the object configured before the call (in this case it is the instance of something) and the second would be the result of the `Calculate` method. now the thing is that the result of `Calculate` is different for every call (because it's random) and the `something.a` should be different for each call as well because its random too but every time the `CalculateContinuation`  is hit something refers to the instance of Something which was configured in the final iteration of loop in `DoSomething2Async`. (if it would be hit before loop I think it would refer to the object configured at that time). I mean I get `MessageBoxes` where result of `Calculate` is different but `something.a` is not. I've been trying to solve this for two days I cant figure out what to do. I tried to pass the clone of `something` I tried to add `something`s to collection and pass the last on each iteration, but nothing gives me the result desired. may be somebody had a problem like this. what is the solution in this situation. thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Human readable Code

```
private void RegisterAllUsers()
{
    Person person = new Person(string.Empty);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        person.Name = "Some name"; // different on each iteration

        // create registration task
        var registrationTask = new Task<bool>(()
            => RegisterUser(person));

        // assign continue with, first parameter is person itself and second is the result of RegisterUse
        registrationTask.ContinueWith((task)
            => RegistrationCallback(person, registrationTask.Result));

        registrationTask.Start();
    }
}

private bool RegisterUser(Person person)
{
    // do registration stuff

    return true; // or false if failes 
}

private void RegistrationCallback(Person person, bool succeded)
{
    // when this method executed the reference of person is whatever was set in RegisterAllUsers
    // for the last time, but i want to have reference to the user which was configured on each iteration

    // suppose 1st user is Steve 2nd is Bob and 3rd is Jack
    // when this methid is hit the name of the user is Jack on all 3 callbacks but the succeded parameter
    // is whatever the RegisterUser returned

    // update registered user's status
}
```

RegisterAllUsers is call like this

```
Task.Run(() => RegisterAllUsers());
```

Comment: With `Something` and `Something2` your code is hard to follow. Please edit your question and use the real names, or at least less similar ones.

Comment: OK I'll try my best wait a few minutes

Comment: There you go. I've made some changes to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

In relation to your edited part of code:

`Person` has only one instance: `person`. Then you start your loop with `i`. Loop fills up `person.Name` for each `i` and in the meantime it start a task. Unfortunately before task is being started, the foreeach loop is finished and the `person` instance contains only last assigned value. So you have three scheduled tasks and each of which takes one `person` instance that has only last values assigned to its `Name` since the `Name` depends on `i` which I have inferred from the problem description.

To fix the problem create the instance of `Person` for each task and use `j` variable inside your loop (closure issue):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    Person person = new Person(string.Empty);
    person.Name = "Some name"; // depends on j this time rather on i
....
```